# Loss of logistic regression model not decreasing through gradient descent

Tags: python, machine-learning, logistic-regression, gradient-descent

I'm a beginner to machine learning and have been trying to implement gradient descent to try and optimize the weights of my model. I am trying to develop the model from scratch and I have reviewed a lot of code online but my implementation still doesnt seem to decrease the loss of the model with the loss oscillating between 0.2 and 0.1. The loss function I used is L = (y - hypothesis)**2. Any help would be appreciated

```
    for z in range(self.iterations):
        print(z)
        cost = 0
        for x in range(self.batch_size):
            derivatives = np.zeros(self.num_weights)
            ran = self.random_row()
            row = self.X.iloc[[ran]]
            cost += self.loss(row, self.y[ran])
            error = self.y[ran] - self.predict(row)
            for i in range(len(derivatives)):
                derivatives[i] = derivatives[i] + (error * (row.iloc[0,i] * -2))
                derivatives[i] = derivatives[i] * learning_rate
                self.weights[i] = self.weights[i] - derivatives[i]
```

Comment: How does the loss behave? Oscillating or diverging? What is the learning rate?

Comment: The loss is oscillating with a learning rate of 0.0001

Comment: Lowering the LR usually solves the oscillation, however I suggest you to add some details to your question.

Answer (score 1):

This is the incorrect loss function. For binary/two-class logistic regression you should use the cost function of

[image: binary logistic regression cost equation]

where h is the hypothesis.

You can find an intuition for the cost function and an explaination of why it is what it is in the 'Cost function intuition' section of this article [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-logistic-regression-in-python-301d27367c24).

With this cost function, you will need to use a different gradient: [image: gradient equation].

Note that here different notation is used and the cost function is represented by J(θ) where θ is a vector of weights for this model. A derivation of this equation can be found [here](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/derivative-of-log-loss-function-for-logistic-regression-9b832f025c2d).

In general, here are some helpful articles about implementing logistic regression:

1. https://towardsdatascience.com/building-a-logistic-regression-in-python-301d27367c24
2. https://www.baeldung.com/cs/gradient-descent-logistic-regression
3. https://machinelearningmastery.com/implement-logistic-regression-stochastic-gradient-descent-scratch-python/
4. https://medium.com/@martinpella/logistic-regression-from-scratch-in-python-124c5636b8ac
5. https://dhirajkumarblog.medium.com/logistic-regression-in-python-from-scratch-5b901d72d68e

Answer (score 0):

iam beginner in learning machine learning. I usually use sklearn library in python. you can put the code at head line `from sklearn.linear model import SGDlassifier` then the SGDClassifer fit with your data by using `SGDClassifier.fit(X_train,y_train)`